# ZIP files with name "soda-en-US-v1001-1.zip" appearing on their own on Android 11

Tags: files, zip

I have .ZIP files appearing on my Android 11 phone on their own. I don't know why they're there, and I don't know where they're coming from. Their located under Google, Download cache. 24 files named as follows:

soda-en-US-v1001-1.zip

All file names are the same except for the number at the end. All files are 50.05mb. If I try to open them, it says "unable to open archive. File is either corrupt or an unsupported format." I  didn't create these files, nor have I downloaded anything.

Why are these files being created on their own?

Comment: Looks like "soda" is a short-form of "[Speech On-Device API](https://hackaday.io/project/164399-android-offline-speech-recognition-natively-on-pc/log/176945-soda-speech-on-device-api)" and related to Android on-device speech recognition. There's [a similar discussion on Google Support (in Indonesian)](https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/115322606/soda-en-us-v1000-f51-zip-file-ini-selalu-didownload-google-ketika-saya-terhubung-ke-wifi) mentioning to disable the Google app.

Comment: So, I went to Google settings-Voice-Offline Speech recognition and removed automatic downloads. Is this what is being referred to?

Comment: That suggestion was deemed as not working by the OP. Instead, it was suggested to also disable the Google app from the Android settings, and that's what the OP followed and deemed working. However, feel free to post an answer if either works well for you personally.

Comment: How, specifically, would I disable the Google app from the Android settings on my Android 11 phone?

Comment: Clarification - my Google app is always disabled because I never use Google. However, these files still show up. Are you referring to something other than what I'm thinking?

Answer (score 0):

For me this approach worked: force stop download manager, then clear its data and cache, and then restart the phone.

Answer (score 0):

The automatic downloading of soda-en-US-....zip files stopped when I deleted one of my old, useless Gmail accounts that I used to sign in to the Twitter website in old days. So when I deleted that Gmail account from my Android, the soda-en-US-v1001-1.zip file's downloading also stopped.

Also, I disabled automatic downloading in the Google setting account icon in the Google app - Settings - Voice - Offline speech recognition - Automatic download using WiFi - Off.